# How to really make this operation async in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have very recently started checking out asyncio for python. The use case is that, I hit an endpoint `/refresh_data` and the data is refreshed (from an S3 bucket). But this should be a non blocking operation, other API endpoints should still be able to be serviced.

So in my controller, I have:

```
def refresh_data():
  myservice.refresh_data()
  return jsonify(dict(ok=True))
```

and in my service I have:

```
async def refresh_data():
  try:
    s_result = await self.s3_client.fetch()
  except (FileNotFound, IOError) as e:
    logger.info("problem")
  
  gather = {i.pop("x"):i async for i in summary_result}
  # ... some other stuff
```

and in my client:

```
async def fetch():
  result = pd.read_parquet("bucket", "pyarrow", cols, filts).to_dict(orient="col1")
  return result
```

And when I run it, I see this error:

```
TypeError: 'async for' requires an object with __aiter__ method, got coroutine
```

I don't know how to move past this. Adding `async` definitely makes it return a `coroutine` type - but, either I have implemented this messily or I haven't fully understood asyncio package in Python. I have been working off of simple examples but I'm not sure what's wrong with what I've done here.

Comment: Hello, I do not see any `async for` in your code example, please provide minimal reproduceable example

Comment: done, sorry, i've been trying various things at any given time